# How can I specify the subnet of an RDS or DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I would like to specify the subnet for a DynamoDB or RDS database to decrease the latency when I access the database from my EC2 server. Is this possible? Right now, the latency is about 0.1s for reads from the DynamoDB server by the EC2 server in the same region, which seems much too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you measure the latency? I'm extremely surprised to hear that you're gettin 100ms latency with Dynamo, from an EC2 host. In my experience DynamoDB gives pretty consistent latency in the low tens of milliseconds: 10-20ms in the 99th percentile and 10ms in the 90th percentile latency is pretty typical. The median latency (p50) is even lower with the majority or requests being completed in 4-5ms.

Of course, how long requests take also depends on how much data you're shuttling around. Writing large items for instance may take longer than simply updating a smaller item.

If you do want to configure a VPC endpoint for DynamoDB though, that is totally possible and you can accomplish that using the `aws ec2 create-vpc-endpoint` command as shown in the following guide:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/vpc-endpoints-dynamodb.html

**Note** In your question you're asking about RDS as well. While RDS does not offer VPC endpoints as a service, an RDS instance is already within your VPC so it doesn't really make sense to talk about VPC endpoint for RDS databases. You can simply create the instance and not even give it public internet access. Requests to the RDS databases will simply flow through the VPC router, straight to the RDS instance endpoint, all within the VPC.